# How to pass props to child selector in selector ngrx anguar 7

Tags: angular, parameters, selector, ngrx

Can I pass props to all child selector in store/index.ts ngrx 7 angular 7 like that :

I will call in component :
      this.filteredUser = this.store.pipe(select(selectVisibleBooks, {id: this.id}));

```
export const selectUserById = createSelector(
  selectUserEntities,
  (entities, props) => props.id && entities[props.id]
);

export const selectVisibleBooks = createSelector(
  selectUserById(props), // I want use prop id here
  selectAllBooks,
  (selectedUser: User, allBooks: Book[]) => {
    if (selectedUser && allBooks) {
      return allBooks.filter((book: Book) => book.userId === selectedUser.id);
    } else {
      return allBooks;
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: If we trust the docs, you are supposed to be able to do that, are you meeting any problems.

Comment: i couldn't. selectUserById return undefined

Answer (score 0):

`{id: this.id}` is passed through all your child selectors.

Comment: i couldn't. selectUserById return undefined